# Osclass display locations on sidebar

Tags: php, mysql, location, osclass

I have problem i need to display locations like this:

-Country

--regions

---cities

-Country

--regions

---cities

I have Countries and regions but i don't know how can i display cities by region.

This is my code:`

```
                    <?php if(osc_count_countries() > 0 ) { ?>

                    <div class="box location">

                        <h3><strong><?php _e("Location", 'bender') ; ?></strong></h3>

                        <ul>

                        <?php while(osc_has_countries() ) { ?>

                            <li><a href="<?php echo osc_country_url( array( 'sCountry' => osc_list_country_code() ) ) ; ?>"><?php echo osc_country_name() ; ?> <em>(<?php echo osc_country_items() ; ?>)</em></a></li>





                        <?php  if (osc_country_name() =='Austria')  { ?>

                            <ul>

                                <?php View::newInstance()->_erase('regions');







        View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView('regions', Search::newInstance()->listRegions('AT', '>') ) ; 



                                if(osc_count_regions('AT') > 0 ) { 



                                while(osc_has_regions('AT') ) { ?>

                                    <li><a href="<?php echo osc_search_url(array('sRegion' => osc_region_name()));?>"><?php echo osc_region_name() ; ?> <em>(<?php echo osc_region_items() ; ?>)</em></a></li>

                                <?php } ?>   

                            </ul>

                            <?php }  ?>







                        <?php }  ?>`
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the helpers in the documentation?

https://doc.osclass.org/HLocation.php

It is quite similar to the list countries and regions:

```
<?php if(osc_count_countries() > 0 ) { ?>  
    <?php while(osc_has_countries()) { ?>
        ...
    <?php } ?>  
<?php } ?> 

<?php if(osc_count_regions() > 0 ) { ?>  
    <?php while(osc_has_regions()) { ?>
        ...
    <?php } ?>  
<?php } ?>
```

but:

```
<?php if(osc_count_cities() > 0 ) { ?>  
    <?php while(osc_has_cities()) { ?>
        ...
    <?php } ?>  
<?php } ?>
```

Okay, here is the full code:

```
<?php if(osc_count_countries() > 0 ) { ?>
    <?php while(osc_has_countries()) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo osc_country_url();?>"><?php echo osc_country_name() ; ?> <em>(<?php echo osc_country_items() ; ?>)</em></a></li>
        <?php if(osc_count_regions() > 0 ) { ?> 
            <?php while(osc_has_regions()) { ?> 
                <li><a href="<?php echo osc_region_url();?>">-<?php echo osc_region_name() ; ?> <em>(<?php echo osc_region_items() ; ?>)</em></a></li>
                <?php if(osc_count_cities(osc_list_region_id()) > 0 ) { ?>  
                    <?php while(osc_has_cities()) { ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo osc_city_url();?>">--<?php echo osc_city_name() ; ?> <em>(<?php echo osc_city_items() ; ?>)</em></a></li>
                    <?php } ?>  
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?> 
<?php } ?>
```

This will load all countries >> regions >> cities like:

- Country

  - Region

    - City
- Country

  - Region

    - City

...
which is a bunch of data depending on how many cities you have.
Therefore I recommend you to use Ajax instead.

/index.php?page=ajax&action=cities&regionId=%

Comment: <?php while(osc_has_cities($region = 'what shoud be here?') ) { ?>  how take region id?

Comment: its not working.... ihave error: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1048576 bytes) in /home/u575073028/public_html/oc-includes/osclass/core/View.php on line 67 and without cities it display also wrong like: country and all regions and againg countries...

Comment: Like I said, it will load a buch of data. Increase memory limit in php.ini (server side) in case it's not a shared hosting, otherwise you'll have to contact your hosting provider to do so, which in most cases, usually rejected. In case you have root access, which is most likely VPS or Dedicated server, you should find php.ini file at /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini or you can make sure of the location by using: <?php phpinfo(); ?>.

But again, I don't recommend to load this amount of data upon loading webpage. Use Ajax instead!

Comment: but without part of cities its not working, it display countries but under first country display all regions and than rest countries. I wanna display only countries, regions and cities only with item, cities ordered by regions like tree menu...

Comment: Well, this was not mentioned in the original post. I think this will do the trick for showing locations with active items only: http://forums.osclass.org/general-help/get-'navigation'-to-show-cities-instead-of-region/msg2055/#msg2055 I haven't tested the code, but it looks okay to me.

Comment: How can i use AJAX for it? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

i try with this code from http://forums.osclass.org/general-help/get-'navigation'-to-show-cities-instead-of-region/

```
<ul>
<?php while(osc_has_list_regions()) { ?>
    <li> <a href="<?php echo osc_update_search_url( array( 'sRegion'=>osc_list_region_name(), 'sCity'=>'' ) ); ?>"><?php echo osc_list_region_name(); ?></a> <em>(<?php echo osc_list_region_items(); ?>)</em>
        <?php if ( osc_count_list_cities(osc_list_region_name()) > 0 ) { ?>
            <ul>
                <?php while( osc_has_list_cities() ) { ?>
                    <li> <a href="<?php echo osc_update_search_url( array( 'sRegion'=>osc_list_region_name(), 'sCity' => osc_list_city_name() ) ); ?>"><?php echo osc_list_city_name(); ?></a> <em>(<?php echo osc_list_city_items(); ?>)</em> </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        <?php } ?>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

but this code display regions and all cities from all regions, how display regions and their cities only with items...